# how to deploy GWT to Jboss 7 and assign domain to the deployment?

Tags: spring, hibernate, gwt, deployment, jboss

I have GWT application use Hibernate and Spring capabilities, how I can deploy this to JBoss 7 and assign my domain to this deployment (www.mydomain.com),

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploying a GWT application on Jboss ..

```
1)Compile you gwt web application
2)Copy  the war file 
3)Add all libraries(jar files) in lib folder of war file 
4)Rename your war as mydoamin.war
5)Put the war in jboss/standalone/deployments/
6)create a dodeploy file   like mydoamin.war.dodeploy (type should be file)
7)From command line  enter into Jboss/bin  folder
8)To run the jboss  type standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0  
9)Then it start deploy all the dodeploy war files 
10)If jboss created the file mydoamin.war.deployed  ...successfully deploy .(you can acceess as http://localhost:8080/mydoamin)
11)If failed it will generate mydoamin.failed  ..  oops some thing went wrong ..check the console and resolve those exceptions
```

All the best .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to access my app using (http://localhost:8080/mydoamin) I want like this (www.mydomain.com)

Comment: In Standalone.xml of jboss server you have to give default root =no. .To do that you have to own(i.e buy) an DNS  registered domain .Its an non coding part.

 refer:
http://www.openscope.net/2010/01/17/virtual-hosting-with-jboss/

Comment: Sorry ..i thought you will catch the term virtual host ..here is the jboss docs for jboss 7 virtual host :)  https://community.jboss.org/wiki/VirtualHostsWithJBossAS7

Comment: Have a quick look on this also .http://blog.egkv.me/2012/07/17/jboss-7-virtual-hosts/